# Describe $Spec( \mathbb C[x,y]/x(x-a))$ where $a$ is some complex number.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, zariski-topology

I'm solving some exercises from my class notes on Commutative Algebra,On the following exercise I got stuck:

Describe $Spec( \mathbb C[x,y]/x(x-a))$ where $a$ is some complex number.

As far as I know the maximal ideals of $\mathbb C[x,y]$ are of the form $(x-a,y-b)$ where $a,b \in \mathbb C$.But I don't know any result regarding prime ideals of $\mathbb C[x,y]$,So I am facing difficulty in solving this exercise.I'm pretty sure that we've to use the Correspondence theorem of ideals for solving this particular problem,but I'm unable to solve this problem.Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(i) If $a\neq0$ the prime ideals you want are the maximal ideals $(x-a,y-b)\; (b\in \mathbb C)$ and $(x,y-b)\; (b\in \mathbb C)$ about which you already know **PLUS** the two prime but not maximal ideals $(x)$ and $(x-a)$.

(ii) If $a=0$ the prime ideals you want are the maximal ideals $(x,y-b)\; (b\in \mathbb C)$ **PLUS** the prime ideal $(x)$

Thinking geometrically (which one should!) this is evident:
In (i) we obtain  the closed (=traditional) points of the union of the two lines  $x=0, x=a\:$ **PLUS** one generic  (=Grothendieck)  point for each line.
And in (ii) we obtain the closed points of the non reduced line $x^2=0$ **PLUS** its generic point.

**Note carefully**
Quite generally, given a ring $A$, its spectrum (as a topological space) is homeomorphic to that of its reduction $A_{red}=A/Nil(A)$.
In particular the spectrum of a quotient $A=R/I$ is homeomorphic to that of $A_{red}=R/\sqrt I$ and in our case we have (in accordance with (ii)) homeomorphisms $$Spec( \mathbb C[x,y]/(x^2))\equiv Spec( \mathbb C[x,y]/(x))\equiv Spec(\mathbb C[y])$$

Comment: :Thank you,Best Regards,

Comment: You are welcome, dear Arpit.

Answer (score 1):

Let's observe that if $a \neq 0$ the ideals $(x)$ and $(x-a)$ are coprime,  by CRT you obtain:

$$\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{x(x-a)} \simeq \frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{(x)} \oplus \frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{(x-a)} \simeq \mathbb{C}[y]\oplus \mathbb{C}[y]$$

Now is easy to look at the prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x]\oplus \mathbb{C}[x]$ and I think you can easely understand their correspondence in the ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Otherwise, if $a=0$, by isomorphism theorem you obtain 
$$\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{x^2} \simeq \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(x^2)} \left[y \right]=A[y]$$
Now if $P$ is a prime ideal of $A[y]$ think to $P \cap A$ : it is a prime ideal of $A$ and there are not ideals of this kind that contains $x^2$...

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(x(x-a))$ decomposes as $(x) \cap (x-a)$. Thus $\textrm {Spec}$ of this corresponds to the disjoint union of two lines in $\mathbb C^2$.

However, if $a=0$, *geometrically*, this is only one line, but it is a so-called "fat line", in that the ideal is representend by $x^2$.

Comment: maximal Spec of the ring correspond to disjoint union of two lines, but as in Spec there is the extra ideal (0), it has a generic point, as mentioned in the answers above.